# smartsheet api with c#

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I am using Smartsheet through C# to insert rows into the existed sheets executing but when come to adding rows to the sheet it giving error like this "You are not authorized to perform this action "   please help iam stuck there

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should take a look at [ask] to improve your question. For example, including your code that perform this action would help.

Answer (score 1):

Error response codes are documented here: http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#errors

Most likely you have not set the Access Token correctly. Do other API calls succeed?

Comment: Yes Api method calls like GetCurrentUser and GetServerInfo is working fine but when inserting row using RowResources.AddRows it giving error you are not authorized to perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you check what your [permission level](https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/1155182-sharing-permission-levels) is for that sheet. To do so, you could execute a [List Sheet Shares](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#list-sheet-shares) (and examine the response to determine your permission level) or you could simply login to the Smartsheet web console and see if you're able to add/edit data in the same sheet that's giving you the error via API. If you have only "Viewer" rights for the sheet, that would explain the error (since viewers aren't able to add/edit data).